# С языка JS на русский (объяснение небольшого фрагмента кода)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Первый раз взаимодействую с JS, и на глаза попался вот такой вот код.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  fix_spell = function(data) {
   data.forEach(function(elem) {
      $('#text_field').val(
        $('#text_field').val().replace(
          elem['word'], elem['s'][0] || elem['word']
        )
      );
    });
```

Понимаю, что здесь для каждого элемента на странице идет замена, но вот что на что меняется?

Непонятна именно эта строка:

```
elem['word'], elem['s'][0] || elem['word']
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь)

Comment: _"именно эта строка"_ это аргуенты функции `replace`, что менять, и через запятую на что менять. или не менять (менять на ту же самую строку)

Comment: @teran, да, я это понимаю, также понимаю, что элемент слово меняется на слово или....вот тут то и загвоздка, что это за конструкция такая `elem['s'][0]`?

Comment: "для каждого элемента на странице" - это откуда? Только для одного элемента с `id="text_field"`. Да и то, где вызывается эта `fix_spell` - неизвестно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так будет понятнее:

```
  $('#text_field').val(
    $('#text_field').val().replace(
      elem.word, elem.s[0] || elem.word
    )
  );
```

или

```
  if (elem.s[0]) {
    $('#text_field').val(
      $('#text_field').val().replace(elem.word, elem.s[0])
    );
  }
```